# Baking tezos-node binary error when baking out of the node

Tags: node

In my current team, we are renewing our infrastructure going to instances GCE. We have almost everything working fine.  There's one increment that we really like to do that is baking the binary outside the node and then copy to and from on bucket on cloud that binary.

So we have one pipeline building this binary and copying it to the node properly.
The issue is that when we do that we get the following errors:

./tezos-node: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This error just happens when the binary is built outside the node. When building on the node it works properly. The pipeline executes exactly the same steps that when executing in the nodes.  I'm using a node running Ubuntu 20.04 and in the pipeline is a docker image with Ubuntu 20.04.
This is the commands executed in the pipeline and nodes:

## Rust

wget https://sh.rustup.rs/rustup-init.sh
chmod +x rustup-init.sh
./rustup-init.sh --profile minimal --default-toolchain 1.44.0 -y
source /root/.cargo/env

## Zcash parameter for Tezos

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zcash/zcash/master/zcutil/fetch-params.sh
chmod +x fetch-params.sh
./fetch-params.sh

## Installing OPAM

echo | sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh) --version 2.0.9
opam init
opam update
opam switch create 4.10.2
eval `opam config env`
eval $(opam env)

## Checkout Tezos

git clone https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos.git
cd tezos
git checkout latest-release
git rev-parse HEAD

#Tezos dependencies and compile
apt-get install -y cargo
make build-deps
eval $(opam env)
make

I really appreciate your help. Many thanks!

Luthiano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the libffi6 (probably 7 for you on Ubuntu 20) package somewhere:

```
Ubuntu 18:
 $ find /usr/ -name "libffi.so*"
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so

 $ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so*
 libffi-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so
 libffi6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have a doubt about this. Because the same node has a package that was built direct. And that binary works well in the same environment.  I really arrive in moments of despair here where I was not able to move anymore.

Comment: Make sure that package is installed in both environments and you shouldn't have to worry. Make sure to install it within docker container too.